# Laravel Eloquent: hasMany involving 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 models :

- User (Tom, James, ..)
- Skill (Math, French, ..)
- Diploma (Diploma 1, Diploma 2)

A User has many Skills, and many Diplomas for that skill.

For example, Luke has a Diploma 1 and 2 in Math, and Diploma 1 in French.
James just has just a Diploma 2 in Math.

So far, I have 5 tables:

- users
- skills
- diplomas
- user_skill (links user with skills)
- user_skill_diploma (links user_skill with diplomas)

I have no problem linking the user with the skills, but I have trouble linking the skills and the diploma together... A user has many skills, but a skill doesn't really have many diplomas, it's the user who has a combination of skills and diplomas...

I want to be able to filter users by their skill/diploma combination (for example, I want all users who have a diploma A of math)
Also, I want to be able to get all skills/diploma combinations for a user

Is their a native Eloquent way of linking user with the skill/diploma combination? Or should I right the raw queries myself ?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: So the user_skill has only one diploma? and it is related to user skill not to the skill right?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: You might want to check out scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: when you asking a question please try to put our code what you have tried so far. we are not available for write free code for you

Comment: Well I was not asking for code, but to know if it was possible to link models that way, what kind of relations it was. I haven't really start coded yet because I can't figure out what kind of relations those models have.